# Position a button after the last listviewitem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

My ListView is bound to an ObservableCollection, is there a way to position a button after the last listviewitem? What I have done is define the button in the DataTemplate like below:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TestDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>            
            <TextBlock x:Name="SeletedFilterText" Text="{Binding}" />
            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.TestCommand,ElementName=TestListView}"                    
                Content="Test"                    
                Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource testConverter}}"
                Grid.Column="1"/>        
    </Grid>      
</DataTemplate>
```

In my ViewModel, I define a string variable to store the last item. The ItemSource(an Observable) may add or remove item, every time I set the last of the Collection to the LastItem variable. In the converter, compare the binding content with the LastItem, if the value is true, display the Button, if false, hide it. But the converter will never be triggered. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest not to have backup field in ViewModel to keep track of lastItem in collection.

You can do that with only **`Converter` in place which will return true or false if passed `ListViewItem` is last item in `ListView` or not**.

In case you want to call the converter whenever underlying `ObservableCollection` add/remove item in it, I would suggest to **pass `Count` property to converter so that converter gets fired whenever item is added/removed from collection.**

---

**Converter code:**

```
public class IsLastItemInContainerConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DependencyObject item = (DependencyObject)values[0];
        ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);

        if (ic != null)
        {
            return ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item)
                      == ic.Items.Count - 1;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button Content="Test">
   <Button.Style>
     <Style TargetType="Button">
       <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
       <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Value="True">
           <DataTrigger.Binding>
             <MultiBinding
                  Converter="{StaticResource IsLastItemInContainerConverter}">
                <Binding Path="."
                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                           AncestorType=ListViewItem}"/>
                <Binding Path="DataContext.SourceCollection.Count"
                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                    AncestorType=ListView}"/>
             </MultiBinding>
           </DataTrigger.Binding>
           <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
         </DataTrigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
   </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Replace `SourceCollection` with your `ObservableCollection name` in dataTrigger.

Comment: When I delete an item from the collection, the button also collapsed

Comment: Is Converter gets fired?

Comment: No, when I add an item, the converter fired, but when I delete an item, it not

Comment: Sorry! My mistake! It works well! Really an awesome solution!

Comment: Hi, when I delete the last filter, the converter is fired with a endless loop. :(

Comment: It shouldn't ideally. There has to be something missing in your code. Works well at my end with sample code.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you create a custom control for your use case. Like so:

```
public class ButtonListView : ListView
{
    static ButtonListView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ButtonListView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ButtonListView)));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Command", typeof (ICommand), typeof (ButtonListView), new PropertyMetadata(default(ICommand)));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand) GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ButtonContent", typeof (object), typeof (ButtonListView), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    public object ButtonContent
    {
        get { return (object) GetValue(ButtonContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonContentProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And use this style:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBox.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBox.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFD9D9D9" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonListView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonListView}">
                <Border Name="Bd"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                        Padding="1">
                    <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  Focusable="false">
                        <StackPanel>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            <Button Content="{TemplateBinding ButtonContent}" Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"></Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ListBox.Disabled.Background}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ListBox.Disabled.Border}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can then use it like so:

```
<wpfSandbox:ButtonListView ButtonContent="Press" Command="{Binding ...}"/>
```

This way you don't need to Keep track of the order in the `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I have tried it and it works! But my ListView has a complex style, could you tell me which part of the style I could import to my style in your code? Thanks!

Comment: This part:<StackPanel>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            <Button Content="{TemplateBinding ButtonContent}" Command="{TemplateBinding Command}"></Button>
                        </StackPanel>

Comment: In this way, the button always below the ListView, not follow the last listviewitem.

Comment: You sure? Maybe thats a Problem with your style? It works if you use my example code correctly.

Comment: My ListViewItem arranged horizontally in a WrapPanel, if the first line is full, turn to the scecond line.

Comment: Ok under that circumstances you would need to create a custom wrappanel instead of a custom listview. Maybe you are better of with one of the other answers. For me it's more like a personal choice to not keeping track of the individual positions of items in a collection, but in this case it might be the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and it's very easy:

1. Define your Observable collection with generic type of `<DependencyObject>`
2. Add a custom object to the end of the collection. (it can be a something like a ViewModel for Button if you want to add commands or etc to it)
3. Don't set the `ItemTemplate` of your ListView (or ItemsControl or etc)
4. Instead, define two `DataTemplate`s **without** `x:Key` in the resources and set their `DataType` to the desired types. It should be like `"{x:Type local:ButtonVm}"` or `"{x:Type vm:ListViewItemType}"`

Now the template for each item automatically set to the data template that matches the type of that item.

### Example:

(note that you can move ListView.Resources to Window.Resources if the templates can be reused elsewhere)

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ListItemVm}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemText}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ButtonVm}">
            <Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ButtonText}"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Items.Add(new ListItemVm { ItemText = "something" } );
        Items.Add(new ListItemVm { ItemText = "something" } );
        Items.Add(new ListItemVm { ItemText = "something" } );
        Items.Add(new ButtonVm { ButtonText = "click here" } );
}
private ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> _items = new ObservableCollection<DependencyObject>();
public ObservableCollection<DependencyObject> Items { get { return _items; } }
```

one viewModel for each type of item:

```
public class ListItemVm : DependencyObject
{
    public string ItemText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ItemTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemText", typeof(string), typeof(ListItemVm), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

}

public class ButtonVm : DependencyObject
{
    public string ButtonText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonVm), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

    public Command ButtonCommand
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonCommandProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonCommand", typeof(Command), typeof(ButtonVm), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));
}

public class Command : ICommand { /* simple implementation of ICommand */ }
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply! Is it possible to provide me a sample?

Comment: In this way, if I add an item to the collection, I have to remove the button first and after the item is added, add the button again. In my scenario, the button must stay as the last item of the collection. Thanks

Comment: You can use Items.Insert(Items.Count-1, newItem)